# How to rename duplicate lines with awk?

Tags: awk, duplicates, rename

I have a file with 1 million lines and some lines are duplicate. I would like to rename the duplicate lines by appending "variant" + a number.
The file is formatted as follows:

```
I am a test line
She is beautiful
need for speed
Nice day today
I am a test line
stack overflow is fun
I am a test line
stack overflow is fun
I have more sentences
I am a test line
She is beautiful
Speed for need
stack overflow is fun
Let's stop here
```

Desired results:

```
    I am a test line
    She is beautiful
    need for speed
    Nice day today
    I am a test line variant 1
    stack overflow is fun
    I am a test line variant 2
    stack overflow is fun variant 1
    I have more sentences
    I am a test line variant 3
    She is beautiful variant 1
    Speed for need variant 1
    stack overflow is fun variant 2
    Let's stop here
```

Comment: Have you attempted anything for this? Do you have enough memory to hold the lines in memory while processing the file?

Comment: a millon line seems not a big deal, several MB memory...

Comment: I don't know if 8gb memory is enough. I found some code like: nawk '$n in a {$n=$n "_" ++a[$n]}{a[$n];print}' myfile but this code seems to work only if the lines have same length

Comment: Indeed, if one million was literal then that's not a lot of memory needed.

Comment: That awk script is the right idea but I don't know what `$n` is supposed to be there. Something like `$0 in map{$0=$0 " variant " ++map[$0]} {map[$0]=0; print}` should do what you want.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$ awk 'cnt[$0]++{$0=$0 " variant " (cnt[$0]-1)} 1' file
I am a test line
She is beautiful
need for speed
Nice day today
I am a test line variant 1
stack overflow is fun
I am a test line variant 2
stack overflow is fun variant 1
I have more sentences
I am a test line variant 3
She is beautiful variant 1
Speed for need
stack overflow is fun variant 2
Let's stop here
```

Comment: can you explain your solution? )) what is the number 1 in the end of line

Comment: @Estet `1` = `{print}`, you'll see it in at least half of all short awk scripts. If there's anything else in the script you don't understand after a quick glance at the man page or google or adding additional `print` statements to test it yourself, let me know and I'll be happy to answer any specific questions.

Comment: Ohh, i try smthng like this awk  'cnt[$0]++ {if ($0=$0) $7=cnt[$0]-1"@abc.com" ; else $7="@abc.com" } 1' ;; but it only return if actions

Comment: OK, you're going to have to read something about awk syntax before starting to use it. Try a couple of the examples out of the man page. if you can't figure out how to do whatever it is you're trying to do then of course feel free to post a new question on this forum.

Comment: yes, can you check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65836903/renumbering-duplicate-lines-with-counter-awk

Comment: How to retain the same formatting used before substitution?

Comment: @EnthusiastiC this answer is 7 years old, please ask a new question.

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/usr/bin/python

d = {}
with open("xy.txt") as f:
    for line in f:
        line = line.strip()
        if not line: continue

        cnt = d.get(line, 0)
        if not cnt:
            print line
        else:
            print " ".join([line, "variant %d" % cnt])

        d[line] = cnt + 1
```

ok this is not awk, but much easy to read. (ok with my mind...)

Comment: saw your answer, i take back my word. my mind is not that much awk.

Comment: @DynoHongjunFu awk is just a very-stripped-down C inside an implicit `while read line` loop and with implicit `if condition is true then do action` statements (`<condition>{<action>}`) and associative arrays, all of which are present in the tool because they are common to almost all text manipulation operations and text manipulation is the one and only job that awk was created to do. Once you understand that it really is by far the simplest of the Algol-based languages to learn.

Comment: thanks for the very clear explanation! you are a great `awk` ambassador :) and never know the awk hash/dict works that way before.