# Making duplicate record unique using awk

Tags: awk, duplicates

I am trying to use awk to identify duplicate records in a file and apply the changes directly to it. The file has six columns with no headers. My aim is to edit the second column of the duplicate record to make it unique by adding 1 every time it appears. The data looks like this:

```
1 A B C D E
1 A B C D E   (This is a duplicate record1)
1 A B C D E   (This is a duplicate record2)
2 F G H I J
3 K L M N O
```

The desired output

```
1 A   B C D E
1 A-1 B C D E
1 A-2 B C D E
2 F   G H I J
3 K   L M N O
```

**Edit:**

I tried this code `awk 'cnt[$0]++{$0=$0" variant "cnt[$0]-1} 1' file` from this post [How to rename duplicate lines with awk?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29977511/how-to-rename-duplicate-lines-with-awk) but the numbers are added at the end of the record

Comment: Welcome to SO, could you please do add your tried code in your question to make it more clear, thank you(not my downvote btw).

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 I added the code that I tried

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With your shown samples please try following `awk` code.

***One-liner form of above solution is:***

```
awk '++arr1[$0]>1{$2=$2"-"(++arr[$0])}1' Input_file
```

***OR***

```
awk '
++arr1[$0]>1{
  $2=$2"-"(++arr[$0])
}
1
'  Input_file
```

***Explanation:*** Adding detailed explanation for above `awk` code.

```
awk '                               ##Starting awk program from here.
++arr1[$0]>1{                       ##Checking condition if current line occurrence in arr1 is greater than 1
  $2=$2"-"(++arr[$0])               ##Then add values to $2 as per condition. If $0 occurrence in arr is more than 1 then add - followed by its occurrence.
}
1                                   ##1 will print edited/non-edited line.
' Input_file                        ##Mentioning Input_file name here.
```

Comment: Works as intended. but the file doesn't save the changes. Is there an option like `inplace` to save the changes on the file directly?

Comment: @sam_alloy, sure, change solution **to** `awk '++arr1[$0]>1{$2=$2"-"++arr[$2]}1' Input_file > temp && mv temp Input_file` and it should fly then. Let me know how it goes.

Answer (score 1):

In your script just change `$0=$0` to `$2=$2` so you're appending the new text to the end of the 2nd field instead of the end of the line, e.g.:

```
$ awk 'cnt[$0]++{$2=$2 "-" (cnt[$0]-1)} 1' file | column -t
1  A    B  C  D  E
1  A-1  B  C  D  E
1  A-2  B  C  D  E
2  F    G  H  I  J
3  K    L  M  N  O
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 nawk 'BEGIN { _+=_^=___="  " } $_ = $_ ((__=____[$!_]++) ?"-"__:___)' 
 gawk 'BEGIN { _+=_^=___="  " } $_ =__[$!_]++ ? $_ "-"(__[$!_]-!!_):$_ ___'
```

> ```
> mawk/mawk2 '$(_+=_^=_<_) = $_ ((__=___[$-(_=" ")]++) ? "-" __: (_)_)'
> ```

```
1 A   B C D E
1 A-1 B C D E
1 A-2 B C D E
2 F   G H I J
3 K   L M N O
```

concise version :

> ```
> awk '$2=$2 ((_=__[$0]++)?"-"_:"  ")'
> ```